# HTML5 Placeholder Attribute on Textarea via jQuery in IE10

Tags: jquery, html, textarea, placeholder, internet-explorer-10

i was wondering about some weird behaviour in Internet Explorer 10.
On my page, I am adding a textarea with jquery, including a placeholder attribute. Something like this:

```
$('body').append($('<textarea placeholder="Placeholder..."></textarea>'));
```

The placeholder attribute works perfectly fine in IE10 usually... except in this case. I tested it with elements being already on the page in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Aqnt5/1/

As you can see, one textarea (the one added dynamically) treats the placeholder attribute like an actual value - the most annoying behaviour I could imagine...

Does anyone know of this effect and maybe also a workaround? Thanks in advance!

EDIT

I also just realised that it works as expected, after you remove the value by hand. You can remove it via `jQuery.val('')` as well to make it work. I am really confused by this behaviour... But this should be a suitable 'workaround'.
See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aqnt5/5/

Comment: I've just posted a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375208/ie11-jquery-1-8-3-dynamically-added-textarea-with-placeholder-has-text-set-to/23375209#23375209. The issue disappears if you **update jQuery** to a version **> 1.8.3**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not have IE10 to test this on, but this works everywhere else;

```
$('body').append('<textarea></textarea>');
$('textarea').attr('placeholder', 'placeholder');
```

And just double-check that your DOCTYPE is correct for HTML5

Here is a one-liner (broken into several lines here to make it more visible) that you can also do -

```
$('body')
    .append('<textarea></textarea>')
    .find('textarea')
    .attr('placeholder', 'placeholder');
```

Comment: thanks Jay! Your way of setting the placeholder afterwards works perfectly fine in IE10. Also, i found another workaround by removing the value with jQuery (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aqnt5/5/

You can remove the value with jQuery, to make it behave correctly:

```
$('body').append($('<textarea placeholder="Placeholder..."></textarea>').val(''));
```

I dont know why they put the placeholder as a value in the first place...

Comment: This would not be recommended. even due it works, @Jay Blanchard answer is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same thing happen when using `jQuery 1.8.3`: http://jsfiddle.net/wE577/1/.

But if you use a version higher than that, the problem disappears: http://jsfiddle.net/wE577/2/.

I have no clue in what way jQuery causes this bug, but the update fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

`placeholder` is a reserved attribute of HTML5,
since HTML5 is not still defined (and changes might happen to it),
Then not all browsers support all the functions (and dont let me start about IE)

for reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_textarea_placeholder.asp

Comment: thanks Dementic. I know about incompatibility with IE - still, the placeholder attribute works for IE10 most of the times. it's just, when i insert it via jQuery, it is not treated correctly. I was wondering about what actually makes the difference...

Comment: IE tends to have a lot of bugs when you are trying to do some "shortcuts". that is from my personal experience.